# How to fill a div with a white background color but with a lower width and centered?

Tags: css

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;    
    padding: 20px 15%;
    background-color:#f2f2f2
}

#frm-message {
    background-color:white;
}

#menu-lateral {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top:30%;
    position:fixed;
}
.option-menu, .title-option-menu {
    position: relative;
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.title-option-menu {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#main-panel {
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.large-textbox {
    width:60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-lateral">
    <div class="option-menu">Home</div>
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>
    <div class="title-option-menu">Payment</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Create</div>           
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>      
    <div class="title-option-menu">Manage</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Payed</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Pending</div>          
    <div class="option-menu">Deleted</div>          
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>                  
    <div class="option-menu">Exit</div>
</div>
<div id="main-panel">
    <div id="form-payment">
        <div id="frm-message">
            <div>
                *Email:
                <div>
                    <input id="field-email-business" class="large-textbox" name="email" type="email" spellcheck="false" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                *Subject
                <div>
                    <input id="field-subject" class="large-textbox" name="subject" type="text" spellcheck="false" required>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a div that contains form items and I'm trying to set a white color as a background. However, I don't like the result because it is too large and I would like it centered with the form items.

Code:

`css`

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;    
    padding: 20px 15%;
    background-color:#f2f2f2
}

#frm-message {
    background-color:white;
}

#menu-lateral {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top:30%;
    position:fixed;
}
.option-menu, .title-option-menu {
    position: relative;
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.title-option-menu {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#main-panel {
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.large-textbox {
    width:60%;
}
```

`html`

```
<div id="menu-lateral">
    <div class="option-menu">Home</div>
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>
    <div class="title-option-menu">Payment</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Create</div>           
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>      
    <div class="title-option-menu">Manage</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Payed</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Pending</div>          
    <div class="option-menu">Deleted</div>          
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>                  
    <div class="option-menu">Exit</div>
</div>
<div id="main-panel">
    <div id="form-payment">
        <div id="frm-message">
            <div>
                *Email:
                <div>
                    <input id="field-email-business" class="large-textbox" name="email" type="email" spellcheck="false" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                *Subject
                <div>
                    <input id="field-subject" class="large-textbox" name="subject" type="text" spellcheck="false" required>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:
[image]

But I would like to achieve something like this:

[image]

I have tried to set a fixed width to #frm-message but it affects to the form items as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **display:inline-block** and **margin:auto** in the form, setting this properties it will have a dynamic size (in relation to its content) and will remain in the center.

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;    
    padding: 20px 15%;
    background-color:#f2f2f2
}

#frm-message {
    background-color:white;
   
    display:inline-block;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:left;
}
 

#menu-lateral {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top:30%;
    position:fixed;
}
.option-menu, .title-option-menu {
    position: relative;
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.title-option-menu {
    font-weight: bold;
}
#main-panel {
   text-align:center;
}

.large-textbox {
    width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-lateral">
    <div class="option-menu">Home</div>
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>
    <div class="title-option-menu">Payment</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Create</div>           
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>      
    <div class="title-option-menu">Manage</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Payed</div>
    <div class="option-menu">Pending</div>          
    <div class="option-menu">Deleted</div>          
    <div class="separator-bar-menu"></div>                  
    <div class="option-menu">Exit</div>
</div>
<div id="main-panel">
    <div id="form-payment">
        <div id="frm-message">
            <div>
                *Email:
                <div>
                    <input id="field-email-business" class="large-textbox" name="email" type="email" spellcheck="false" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                *Subject
                <div>
                    <input id="field-subject" class="large-textbox" name="subject" type="text" spellcheck="false" required>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```